# Quick way to compare differences between ordered SQL records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL query with first column being the date, and second and third column being some other info. We can assume there is only one record for every day, and we can assume the dates are ordered.

Besides the first column, others contain data of different data types `long`, `int`, `nchar`, `varchar`, etc.

My goal is to figure out if any of the remaining columns have changed on day T when compared versus day T-1, if so (say column N is changed, N could be any of the remaining columns and there might be multiple columns being changed on the same day) I would like to return the date (first column) together with the records on Col N as of Day T versus Col N as of day T-1 (and potentially the header of that column), so my output would be:

```
Date T|Header of Col Modified|Value of Col @ T-1|Value of Col @ T
```

If there are multiple changes, we'll have one row for each change.

Obviously the "slow" way is to bring all the data in somewhere first and then compare the resulting dataset one by one. However I am just wondering if there is any quick way to do it in T-SQL so that I can directly get the result (or something close to the results so that little data manipulation is needed with the output from the query, since it would be much faster for the SQL Server to do the heavy lifting and return only the data I need rather than pretty much the entire table.

I am using SQL Server so a solution in T-SQL is needed.

Comment: *"and we can assume the dates are ordered."* - You cannot unless you query them in an ordered way.

Comment: @GolezTrol That is correct, in reality I am working on a result set that is brought back by running some query however for the sake of simplifying this question I assume the data we are querying is from a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What version of SQL Server do you use?

My solution below returns a raw set of changed rows. The solution just tells you that values in some columns of the two adjacent rows have changed. It doesn't tell you explicitly which columns have changed. You'll need to perform this extra processing (most likely on the client side) to present the data in the way you need. The most important part of the solution is that it reduces the number of rows returned to the client to the minimum.

If you use SQL Server 2012 or above, it has functions [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) and [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx), which can be used to compare previous/next rows:

**Sample data:**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(dt date, v1 int, v2 varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-01', 1, 'a');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-02', 2, 'b');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-03', 2, 'b');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-04', 3, 'b');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-05', 3, 'b');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-06', 3, 'c');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-07', 4, 'd');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-08', 4, 'd');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-09', 4, 'd');
INSERT INTO @T (dt, v1, v2) VALUES ('2015-01-10', 4, 'd');
```

**Query using `LAG`, SQL Server 2012+**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        dt
        ,v1
        ,v2
        ,LAG(v1) OVER(ORDER BY dt) AS PrevV1
        ,LAG(v2) OVER(ORDER BY dt) AS PrevV2
    FROM @T AS T
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE
    v1 <> PrevV1
    OR v2 <> PrevV2
ORDER BY dt;
```

**Result set**

```
dt          v1  v2  PrevV1  PrevV2
2015-01-02  2   b   1       a
2015-01-04  3   b   2       b
2015-01-06  3   c   3       b
2015-01-07  4   d   3       c
```

---

If you use some previous version, then it could be much better from the performance point of view to use a cursor to loop through your rows, compare current with the previous row and insert diff into a temporary table or table variable. Any other solution without `LEAD` or `LAG` would mean that the source table is read at least twice and in worst solution it would be `O(n*n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Starting from SQL Server 2005 there is a function [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). We can use it if the list of dates in you table can have gaps. If you are sure that dates do not have gaps, you can do it without this extra step of generating row numbers and directly join the table on the dates column. It will still be a self-join.

**Query using `ROW_NUMBER`, SQL Server 2005+**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        dt
        ,v1
        ,v2
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt) AS rn
    FROM @T AS T
)
SELECT
    CTE_Curr.dt
    ,CTE_Curr.v1 AS CurrV1
    ,CTE_Curr.v2 AS CurrV2
    ,CTE_Prev.v1 AS PrevV1
    ,CTE_Prev.v2 AS PrevV2
FROM
    CTE AS CTE_Curr
    INNER JOIN CTE AS CTE_Prev ON CTE_Curr.rn = CTE_Prev.rn+1
WHERE
    CTE_Curr.v1 <> CTE_Prev.v1
    OR CTE_Curr.v2 <> CTE_Prev.v2
ORDER BY CTE_Curr.dt;
```

**Result set**

```
dt            CurrV1    CurrV2    PrevV1    PrevV2
2015-01-02    2         b         1         a
2015-01-04    3         b         2         b
2015-01-06    3         c         3         b
2015-01-07    4         d         3         c
```

---

**Execution plan comparison**

Results are the same in both variants, but execution plans are very different. The relative cost of the `LAG` variant is estimated to be 33% and relative cost of the `ROW_NUMBER` variant is 67% - twice as much, because second variant scans and sorts the table twice and sample table is very small. Besides, you can see that in the second variant the table was joined to itself, which lead to reading 100 rows (10*10). If your table is large, it can be very inefficient and it may be better to use a cursor. With the cursor you'll scan the table only once.

**Execution plan with `LAG`**

[image: plan with LAG]

**Execution plan with `ROW_NUMBER`**

[image: plan with ROW_NUMBER]

Comment: The `row_number` = `row_number +1` plan can use a merge join that evaluates each side once (two evaluations in total) and joins the sorted results rather than the 11 evaluations in the plan there. Probably you don't see this as you are using a table variable and you may see it if you add `option(recompile)`.

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith. Also, with real large tables it is imperative to have an index on the `date` column. Execution plan would likely become more efficient. My example is not really valid for such case, because here the table is tiny and it is a table variable without an index.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I am using SQL server 2008 unfortunately so I have to use the long winded path. In the end I am hoping to show only the field that is being changed however this query has simplified the results enough so that I can do a little logic on the presentation layer to get exactly what I want, really appreciate your help (and the very detailed execution plan as well)! What software did you use to make the execution plan or is it some feature in the SQL client that I am not aware of?

Comment: @AZhu, you are welcome. Standard SSMS can show execution plan - there are buttons on a toolbar to `Display estimated execution plan` and `Include actual execution plan`. In fact, underlying T-SQL commands are `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL`, [`SET STATISTICS XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176107.aspx) and similar. To generate these nice looking pictures with the number of rows involved I used the free edition of [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/). It uses same commands internally, but displays information better than SSMS.